# How to add a linear gradient to a background image in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, api

I am making a movie search app using Reactjs, Axios, and MovieDB API. I am currently getting my background image for the API using the following code:

```
const backgroundStyle = {
       backgroundImage: `url(https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500${this.state.background})`,
       backgroundSize: "cover",
       height: "100vh"
     }
```

I would like to add a linear gradient to the background image but when I try to do:

```
background: linear-gradient
```

or

```
background: linearGradient
```

it is still yeallow in react, I am not sure how to implement this. The code I want to use is:

```
linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) ), `url(https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500${this.state.background})`;
```

But put into Reactjs format.

The full code is here:

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import '../CSS/style.css'

export default class Movielist extends React.Component {
  state = {
    title: "",
    popularity: "",
    poster: "",
    background: "",
  }

    clickHandler = (event) => {
        if (event.keyCode === 13) {
           const query = event.target.value;
           const API_KEY = 'caf02a958f137f43327649b2b8721302';
    axios.get(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=${API_KEY}&query=${query}`)
      .then(res => {
        const title = res.data['results'][0]['title'];
        this.setState({ title });

        const popularity = res.data['results'][0]['popularity']
        this.setState({ popularity });

        const poster = res.data['results'][0]['poster_path']
        this.setState({ poster });

        const background = res.data['results'][0]['backdrop_path']
        this.setState({ background })


      })
        }
    }

  render() {
    const backgroundStyle = {
       backgroundImage: `url(https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500${this.state.background})`,
       backgroundSize: "cover",
       height: "100vh"
     }

    return (
      <div id="main-div" style={backgroundStyle}>
        <div id="second-div">
         <input type="search" id="search" onKeyDown={event => this.clickHandler(event)} />
         <h1 id="title">Title: {this.state.title}</h1>
         <h1 id="popularity">Popularity: {this.state.popularity}</h1>
         <img id="poster" src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300${this.state.poster}`} />
      </div>
    </div>

    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can apply the gradient in the property `backgroundImage` when you create `backgroundStyle`. For example,

```js
const backgroundStyle = {
    backgroundImage: `linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), 
url(https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500${this.state.background})`,

    backgroundSize: "cover",
    height: "100vh"
}
```

The value for the `backgroundImage` needs to be a string, you can write css property values for it as usual as long as it is inside a string. And keep in mind these values will be inlined, so it will be most specifc.